# How to add/subtract multiple select statements with null values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, group-by, pivot

I'm trying to subtract the value of two different select statements. The first select statement returns a value and is never null but the second may return NULL. How can I replace NULL with a zero value? I have attempted using COALESCE but still getting a NULL value in return(Example 1). I've tried inserting both select statements into separate tables and using ISNULL (example 2). I've also tried a case statement within the temp table but that doesn't work either (example 3).
Example 1:

```
    Declare @AccountNumber varchar(50) = '1234'
    ,@PayType varchar(15) = 'Full'
    ,@PayPeriod varchar(50) = '2019/05/31'
BEGIN
SELECT (
    SELECT SUM(MyTable.AMOUNT)
    FROM MyTable  
    where  MyTable.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = @AccountNumber
    AND MyTable.PAY_PERIOD = @PayPeriod
    AND PAY_TYPE = @PayType) -
    (SELECT COALESCE(MyTable.AMOUNT,0)
    FROM MyTable  
    where  MyTable.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = @AccountNumber
    AND MyTable.PAY_PERIOD = @PayPeriod
    AND PAY_TYPE = @PayType
    AND CODE = 'ABC')AS FINALRESULT
END
```

Example 2:

```
    Declare @AccountNumber varchar(50) = '1234'
    ,@PayType varchar(15) = 'Full'
    ,@PayPeriod varchar(50) = '2019/05/31'
BEGIN
WITH tempTable1 as (
    (SELECT SUM(MyTable.AMOUNT) as Result
    FROM MyTable  
    where  MyTable.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = @AccountNumber
    AND MyTable.PAY_PERIOD = @PayPeriod
    AND PAY_TYPE = @PayType)
    )
        ,tempTable2 as(
    (SELECT MyTable.AMOUNT AS Result2
    FROM MyTable  
    where  MyTable.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = @AccountNumber
    AND MyTable.PAY_PERIOD = @PayPeriod
    AND PAY_TYPE = @PayType
    AND CODE = 'ABC')
    )
    SELECT (SELECT SUM(Result) FROM tempTable1) - (SELECT ISNULL(Result2 FROM tempTable2),0) as FINALRESULT
END
```

Example 3:

```
    Declare @AccountNumber varchar(50) = '1234'
    ,@PayType varchar(15) = 'Full'
    ,@PayPeriod varchar(50) = '2019/05/31'
BEGIN
WITH tempTable1 as (
    (SELECT SUM(MyTable.AMOUNT) as Result
    FROM MyTable  
    where  MyTable.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = @AccountNumber
    AND MyTable.PAY_PERIOD = @PayPeriod
    AND PAY_TYPE = @PayType)
    )
        ,tempTable2 as(
    (SELECT MyTable.AMOUNT AS Result2
    FROM MyTable  
    where  MyTable.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = @AccountNumber
    AND MyTable.PAY_PERIOD = @PayPeriod
    AND PAY_TYPE = @PayType
    AND CODE = 'ABC')
    )
    SELECT (SELECT SUM(Result) FROM tempTable1) - (
    SELECT
CASE
    WHEN Result2 IS NOT NULL THEN Result2
    ELSE '0'
END AS Result2
FROM tempTable2
    ) as FINALRESULT
END
```

Ultimately, I need to have Result1(100) - Result2(NULL) = 100

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could surround the second subquery with `COALESCE()` to return `0` when no return matches.

But bottom line, I think that your query could be simplified to use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(AMOUNT) - SUM(CASE WHEN CODE = 'ABC' THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) diff
FROM MyTable  
where  ACCOUNT_NUMBER = @AccountNumber
AND PAY_PERIOD = @PayPeriod
AND PAY_TYPE = @PayType
```

Comment: The issue is that `CODE = 'ABC'` only needs to be in the second select statement.

Comment: @Shane: yes I just fixed that in my answer. I would expect that it should do what you want now.